# why script tag after body tag counts in childNodes

Tags: javascript, html, child-nodes

This is a simple **HTML and JS** code, but why scripts tag after body tag, count as childNodes of body!?

**I am trying it in FF 35**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body id='body'>This is only text node</body>
</html>

<script>
    var b;
</script>
<script>
    var b = document.getElementById('body');
    console.log(b.childNodes.item(3).textContent);
</script>
```

Comment: That's broken HTML ... The browser will mangle it as best it can to make it work - look at the document interpretation in the DOM explorer.

Comment: When you write invalid html, the browser tries to turn it into valid html.  In this case it puts the scripts into the body.

Comment: Scripts usually goes in <head> section

Comment: Scripts should go right before the end body tag, when applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as others have pointed out the script tags must be inside the HTML tags otherwise browsers will try and fix it for you with bad consequences.